# Duplicate Locked using Geometry Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

**Question:** I have two models. One duplicate, non-rigged. The other Rigged. Same geometry. In Geometry nodes, how do I make the duplicate mesh wrap over and "lock" onto, literally, vertex to vertex, it's original mesh? When it poses, the other follows. I wouldn't know where to start (nothing works when I use geometry nodes).

**Why (maybe there's an alternative?):** Testing to see if I can use object space normal map's limitations to not respond to light on a rigged model due to having deformations. Curious to know what it would look like on my toon shader with custom-painted normal maps.

Tangent normals don't "snap" like object normals when I average the normals. I had a similar method in Maya back in the day. Was wondering if it's possible to do that here too. Each deformation made on the rigged model is simply moving the vertex in the duplicate model, thus bypassing the rule and allowing object space normals respond to light like it does when you move the model around without a rig. But once you have it rigged, the normals lock.

Comment: what do you mean by wrap over? just duplicate? here you are: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5mqZ.png, but i think you want something else so maybe improve your question to make it clear?

Comment: I edited in that I provide the two geometries.... I did state that one is rigged and the other isn't though. I appreciate the help, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how snapping another duplicate model with the exact same geo, is any different than using the rigged mode itself. but here is how to do it.

- you want to create a *Geometry node modifier* on the duplicate (non-rigged).
- you then bring the rigged object into the node tree via an *object info* node. you also want to set it to relative.
- to get the position from the rigged model to the duplicate you want so use a *sample index* node (blender 3.4 +). set the type to *vector* and domain to *point*

  use the *position* node as the value. use the *index* node as the index.
- now you have the position and need to set the position of the duplicate with the *set position* node.

  just plug the output from the *sample index* node as the *position* input on the *set position* node.

Comment: I might've gotten the node wrong (doesn't seem to work at the moment)? Here's my screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/In12HWQ.png Hopefully when the model poses, the mesh with matching vertex follows, that way although it's deforming, it's at least able to respond to the light. Any time a rigged mesh has object space normal maps in the shader, the light doesn't respond unless you move the light only (The light is as stiff as a brick when the rigged/deformed model is moving).

Comment: you did one mistake. you should use the position node not a value node. (what you are currently doing is setting the position of every to 0. you want to set it to the position of the other mesh)

Comment: I have a feeling it really a shader problem.

Comment: Didn't seem to follow the nearest vertex, sadly. Here's a video: https://i.imgur.com/BzOoAtp.mp4 Mind if I see a screenshot on how you got it to connect and lock, pretty please? I don't mind if it follows nearest shape if vertex is the limitation.

Comment: @Marquis lol. you need to connect the incoming geometry into the set position, and the set position has to go into the original geometry output. (on GN modifiers you can only have one output geometry. it's only with node groups that you can have multiple geometry outputs)

Comment: @Marquis . please learn something about GN before coming here. watch some tutorials or something, so you avoid silly mistakes like that. with the most basic rudimentary understanding of GN  you would of avoided this mistake.
I'm not trying to be mean, but you have to make some effort to understand to tool your using.

Comment: Hi, @shumel .. I know you don't _mean_  to be mean.. but IMO we've got to bend over backwards, on BSE, (where our limited channels can easily be misinterpreted,) to avoid that impression at all costs. Perhaps this tension has arisen because it's actually very difficult to communicate some technical concepts, even simple ones, in words alone. A minimal example, (say 2 IK bones deforming a cylinder?), shared in your answer, might help clear everything up? Worth a try.